# Separating text from alphanumeric

Tags: excel, vba

I want to separate text (names) from numbers (IDs), but there are some exceptions.

Code separates text from numbers but some of the IDs have a letter at the beginning.

How do I obtain full ID with a letter, if applicable?

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NamesandID()

Dim RowNum As Long
Dim eChar As Integer

RowNum = 2
Do Until Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""

    For eChar = 1 To Len(Cells(RowNum, 1))
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(RowNum, 1), eChar, 1)) = True Then
            Cells(RowNum, 3).Value = Cells(RowNum, 3).Value _
              & Mid(Cells(RowNum, 1), eChar, 1)
        Else
            Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = Cells(RowNum, 2).Value _
              & Mid(Cells(RowNum, 1), eChar, 1)
        End If
    Next

    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it correct that you want to extract the content of the first bracket?

Comment: Use Split with '(' as the split character, then split again on item (1) but with ')' as the split character. The I'd will be in item(0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
Sub NamesandID()

Dim RowNum As Long

RowNum = 2
Do Until Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""
    'f you need parenthesis in the name concatenate them at the end, something like below
    'Range("B" & RowNum).Value = Split(Range("A" & RowNum), " (")(0) & " ()"
    Range("B" & RowNum).Value = Split(Range("A" & RowNum), " (")(0) 'no parenthesis at the end
    Range("C" & RowNum).Value = Split(Split(Range("A" & RowNum), " (")(1), ")")(0)

RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be aware that the value `Alex Mohammet etc` gets chopped to only `Alex Mohammet`. Otherwise, yes, `Split()` is definately a good option +

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Also - tried different solutions. Thanks to all of you:)

Comment: @JvdV I see what you mean. Not all records follow same pattern `Name (id)`. You are right in this case. I did not notice that exception!

Answer (score 6):

My two cents.

---

**1)**: Through formulae:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=LET(X,TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A5,")"),"("),HSTACK(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5," ("&X&")","",1),X))
```

---

**2)** Through VBA:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Ann Smith (A123456)", "Tom Ford(2453234)", "Alex Mohammet(4447434)(Text)", "Gerard Kowalski(A6739263)")

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "^(.+?)\s*\(([A-Z]?\d+)\)(.*)$"
    For Each el In arr
        tmp = .Replace(el, "$1$3|$2")
        Debug.Print Split(tmp, "|")(0) 'Print name
        Debug.Print Split(tmp, "|")(1) 'Print ID
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

For those interested in a breakdown of the regular expression used, follow [this](https://regex101.com/r/GJdY0p/1) link.

---

Another option with VBA is to use `Split()`, for example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Ann Smith (A123456)", "Tom Ford (2453234)", "Alex Mohammet (4447434)(Text)", "Gerard Kowalski (A6739263)")
Dim tmp As String

For Each el In arr
    tmp = Split(Split(el, "(")(1), ")")(0)
    Debug.Print Application.Trim(Replace(el, "(" & tmp & ")", ""))  'Print Name
    Debug.Print tmp                                                 'Print ID
Next

End Sub
```

---

Both options would print:

[image]

Comment: I've come up with a slightly different looking regex with exact same result, but you beat me with 2 solutions in one answer before I posted just the regex one :) Note: `LET()` is available in O365 or Excel2021 !

Comment: @Piemol, please can you share your pattern? I know my pattern could be more specific but it felt like this would suffice. Interested in your approach!

Comment: `"(.*) \(([[A-z]?\d+)\)(.*)"` I didn't mind a lower letter in front of the ID, and only allow a single space before the id parenthese starts. So it boils down to the data to expect :)

Comment: That's a bit of a faulty character range to be honest. Note that `A-z` would match [ascii table 65-122](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) including non-alphabetic characters. To ignore case-sensitivity either expand the character class `[A-Za-z]` or use the [inline modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60192760/9758194) to ignore cases. But if it works it works right =)

Comment: Sir, this you call `Two Cents` but I think this is `Masterpiece`, only one approach missing that is `Power Query`, otherwise you have shown all possible ways, this is just amazing, there is no alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a formula:

Name-column: `=MID([@worker],1,FIND("(", [@worker])-1)`

ID-column: `=MID([@worker],FIND("(",[@worker])+1,FIND(")",[@worker])-FIND("(",[@worker])-1)`

[image]

If you are on the Beta-Channel of excel 365 than you might already have `TEXTSPLIT` and `TEXTBEFORE`.